# Linux - update multiple symlinks with a single command

Tags: linux, shell, symlink

When cloning an environment that utilizes symlinks, the symlinks are copied (from production to clone) but they are still pointing to the original (production) files. I want them to be pointing to the cloned files, like:

Original:

```
/production/symlink1 > /production/directory/file1
/production/foo/symlink2 > /production/directory/sub/file2
```

After clone (now):

```
/clone/symlink1 > /production/directory/file1
/clone/foo/symlink2 > /production/directory/sub/file2
```

I want:

```
/clone/symlink1 > /clone/directory/file1
/clone/foo/symlink2 > /clone/directory/sub/file2
```

Is there a way to achieve it with a single command?

Comment: Good question, but off-topic for SO; this belongs on [su] or [unix.se]

Comment: If you're going to be copying/cloning very often, then you should consider using `ln -s ../directory/file1 /production/symlink1` on the production machine.  The relative link would then work correctly when copied to `/clone` or `/some/other/location`.  Don't underestimate the benefits of a relative symlink; be cautious about using them too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created the links yourself? If yes, you could create them with `-r` parameter. See `man ln`:

> -r, --relative
>
> ```
>           create symbolic links relative to link location
> ```

Comment: Really?  Which version of `ln` on which platform?  This [`ln`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln) man page makes no mention of `-r`. _[...time passes...]_ OK; the master GNU manual for [`ln`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#ln-invocation) describes `-r`; it may not be available everywhere yet.

Answer (score 1):

If the links were pointing to absolute paths, they will always point to the same paths after copying. That's the beauty of absolute paths and I don't think you can work around that.

You can try to rewrite those links after copying though. For example if you create a script `relink.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for link; do
    target=$(readlink "$link")
    [[ $target =~ ^/production ]] || continue
    newtarget=$(echo $target | sed -e s?/production?/clone?)
    echo ln -snf "$newtarget" "$link"
done
```

Pass a list of symlinks to this script, it will check if they are pointing to some path under `/production`, and recreate the link with `/production` replaced with `/clone`. You can call it like this for example:

```
find /clone -type l -exec ./relink.sh {} \;
```